# \MongoDB\BSON\Regex in aggregation pipeline - Convert regex from Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to match some input parameters in my API call using the newer Regex library in PHP, but it's not working so far. I'm using string interpolation to achieve this, but its returning any results. Here is my code:

```
$regex = new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex ("^{$this->device_id}:", 'i');

$pipeline = [
      [
        '$match' => [
        '_id' => $regex,

      ]]
```

My document _id are of the type `'london_10:2016-10-05 09'` which is the `device_id:datehour`.

When I var_dump the (string)$regex I get the following, which appears to be working:

```
string(15) "/^london_10:/i"
```

The issue is that when adding this to the pipeline, it returns an empty collection. I have equivalent code which is confirmed working but written in Python, and I need to rewrite it in PHP:

```
    pipeline = [
        {
            '$match': {
                "_id": re.compile("^%s:" %(self.device_id) )
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: So, the regex is fine, you just need to find a way to make your `$pipeline` work. Isn't there any documentation on how to use that?

Comment: Thank you for confirming the regex, I just found that the issue was further downstream in my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The original code in the question is actually correct - I found that the problem wasn't in this part of my pipeline, but further downstream.

Comment: I think that makes your original question off-topic. Rather than posting this answer, either edit the question stating the real issue and posting the right solution, or remove the post.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. My reason is that examples of string interpolation using the newer MongoDB\BSON\Regex are extremely rare and I couldn't find at this point in time. This is an example of a correctly working solution and could help others who have a similar issue.

Comment: I do not negate that your question actually contains some nice things that could help future visitors, but right now it will be impossible to find this information. Consider changing the title and the body to make those strong points stand out. Right now, users who are looking to convert Python regex to PHP will come here and will close the page once they see what it is about.